# Click event handler on marker not firing in iPhone Google Maps version 3 JavaScript

Tags: javascript, iphone, web-applications, google-maps-api-3, web

I want to open an `InfoWindow` on click of the marker using Google Maps API version 3.

I am using:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {      
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
});
```

This code is working fine on BlackBerry and Android, but not working on iPhone.

When I use the Google documentation example for opening an `InfoWindow`, the example is working in Android and BlackBerry, but not when the useragent is an iPhone. For reference of the example:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple-max

The URL above works fine on the Android and BlackBerry useragents, but not when the useragent is an iPhone.

Comment: i have checked reference example link on my iphone and its working fine.

Comment: Works fine on iPad, too.